# Choice of chart and atlas

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Manifold is second countable space. Should charts in atlas also be countable? I don't think it has to be. But somehow the second countable condition enforces me to think like that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be a lot of uncountable atlases, but you can always choose a countable atlas to work with, since [every second-countable space is Lindelöf](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Second-countable_implies_Lindelof). The domains of the charts in the atlas form a cover of the manifold, so you can extract a countable subcover. These charts will give you a countable atlas.

Comment: Thx. A further question how can we cover $\mathbb{R}$ with a countable basis? I saw somewhere, they said you can use $\mathbb{Q}$, but how can rational number eventually cover $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$? I mean I can even prove that cover means unions, unions won't change the rationality of numbers, so at the boundary you will only get rational numbers...

Comment: Every open set in $\Bbb R$ is a union of elements in $${\cal B} = \left\{  \left]x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}\right[ \mid  x \in \Bbb Q, n \in \Bbb N \right\},$$which is clearly countable. Every point in $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is in some little interval with rational radius, contained in $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.

Answer (score 0):

Since basis is countable there must be at most the "continuum number" open sets:

For each open subset we associate the set containing for elements basis open sets that are contained in it. This association is a bijection. Therefore cardinality is no more than the number of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ which is the size of the continuum.

This is definetely not too huge, since even $\mathbb{R}$ has that many opens!

PS Don't worry to much about the axiom. It is just there to ensure you that manifolds are not too big. You can work out a lot without assuming it. But some things like the Whitney's theorem of course not.